# ModbusRTU-MQTT Gateway Hardware

Tags: mqtt

I am using currently a ModbusRTU-MQTT Gateway (HD67933-4-B2)
to access a AC climatisation Device from Toshiba.
A Intesis AC-Interface Device is
converting the proprietary Toshiba Bus from the AC to Modbus RTU.

It is not working, and the devices does not provide any kind of debugging.
I am looking for a different hardware that provides a better way to debug.

My question is:
What alternative Modbus-MQTT Gateway Hardware can be used, that provides a better
way to debug everything.

https://www.adfweb.com/Home/products/Modbus_MQTT.asp?frompg=nav3_28

Comment: maybe you should be talking to Toshiba tech support